# select field when a defining condition in separate rows in same table

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many, entity-attribute-value

[Input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7M9h.png)

I have many-to-many junction table. And I need select product_id when it satisfies several conditions.

```
SELECT product_id  FROM product_attribute WHERE `value`= '15' AND `value` = 'asus'
```

I expect get product_id = 1 but query don't return anything. How to solve it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your sample data as text in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since one record can not be `15` abd `asus` at the same time you need to group the data and check of both conditions are met for the group

```
SELECT product_id 
FROM product_attribute 
WHERE `value`= '15' 
   OR `value` = 'asus'
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(distinct value) = 2
```

Comment: I would use IN rather than OR and count(product_id)  > 1 this would make it easier for future adjustments and also replacing OR with IN as a direct statement and faster in performance.

Comment: It won't be faster with just 2 values in the `IN()`

Comment: @isr5 thanks. I will use IN() because there can be more than 2 values:)